# Displaying access information from get set properties

Tags: c#

When I output the following code on the console, I would get the "Age is wrong" line followed by a '0' (when I input the dog's Age to be -10). I would only want to display the 'Age is wrong' line.

[Program Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJHUR.png)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Animal dog = new Animal();
        dog.Age = -10;
        Console.WriteLine(dog.Age);
    }
}
```

[Animal Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWw4n.png)

```
class Animal
{
    private int age;
    private string color;
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return age;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Age is wrong");
            }
            else
            {
                age = value;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: please try to put the code in the question not in image

Comment: I am quite new to programming so this would be the fastest way for me to get my idea across. Please help if you can thank you!

Comment: just copy & paste the code this will make it easier for me and others to test your code and see where is the problem and help you to solve it

Comment: using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Animal dog = new Animal();
            dog.Age = -10;
            Console.WriteLine(dog.Age);
        }
    }
    
}

Comment: using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Animal
    {
        private int age;
        private int weight;
        private string color; 
        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                return age;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value <0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Age is wrong");
                }
                else
                {
                    age = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Only log the Age when it is not zero is what you want, this is what you should do:

```
if(dog.Age != 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine(dog.Age);
}
```

Comment: Some dogs actually haven't reached the age of 1 yet

Comment: Then set the age to -1 and check for this number as in valid number. Although i would suggest either using `uint` or throwing an exception but that might be to steep of a learning curve

Answer (score 1):

Your `Program` class doesn't know how to detect that the age was wrong - so it just outputs the current age value (0).

You could have a method that returns a boolean, indicating whether setting the age has succeeded:

```
public int Age { get { return age; } } // no setter

public bool SetAge(int newAge)
{
    if (newAge < 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong age: " + newAge);
        return false;
    }

    age = newAge;
    return true;
}
....
if (dog.SetAge(-10))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Age successfully set to " + dog.Age);
}
```

Or you could rely on exception handling:

```
public int Age
{
    get { return age; }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0) throw new Exception("Invalid age: " + value);
        age = value;
    }
}
...
try
{
    dog.Age = -10;
    Console.WriteLine(dog.Age);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error setting age: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Why would the current age value be output as 0? Even though i had inputted the dog.Age as -10?

Comment: The default value for an `int` is 0, and the `age` field isn't changed because of the `if (value < 0)` statement. To demonstrate, try setting the age to 10, and _then_ to -10, you'll see it will still be 10.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already writing to the console in the setter of the property, you could simply move all the writing into the setter block. For example like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Animal dog = new Animal();
        dog.Age = -10;
    }
}

class Animal
{
    private int age;
    private string color;
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return age;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Age is wrong");
            }
            else
            {
                age = value;
                Console.WriteLine(age);
            }
         }
    }
}
```